# How do I interpolate sparse data with a spline?

Tags: interpolation, splines

I have this data:

```
data = 
  {{0.2, 103}, {2, 13.9}, {20, 2.72}, {200, 0.8}, {2000, 0.401}, {20000, 0.433}}
```

Is there any way of finding value at $x=5$ using splines and not an interpolating polynomial?

Comment: `Interpolation[data, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 3][5]`

Comment: recommend `InterpolationOrder -> 1` here.  With that data the higher order interpolation oscillates pretty wildly.

Comment: Interpolation and SplineFit are not the same  : Interpolation[...,Method-> "Spline"...] returns a piecewise polynomial function x->y. SplineFit returns a parametric function t->{x,y}. This last function can represent a curve that goes in every directions, like a circle for example (x get greater, then smaller etc...). For one x there may be several y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I would rescale the domain (logarithmically) to get better spacing between nodes:

```
ifn = Evaluate[
    Interpolation[
      Transpose[{Log@data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]}],
      Method -> "Spline"
      ][Log@#]
    ] &;

LogLogPlot[{ifn[x]}, {x, 0.2, 20000}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@Log@data}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ifn[5]
(*  4.83159  *)
```

Comment: For me, it is still unclear if the OP wants piecewise interpolation or if he wants to interpolate the whole region with one function. Nowadays the questions are so vague and incomplete... +1

Comment: @halirutan Thanks. I assumed "spline" meant spline and the original Q said "not `InterpolatingPolynomial`". I took it that the OP possibly didn't know the spline option to `Interpolation`. But if the question is a real problem, then probably what is wanted is linear interpolation, suggested by george2079, or splines with tension, which I don't think is built in *M*. The inflection points in my answer suggest the interpolation is not very accurate much past the point at $x=2$.